# Create subdirectory and move files

Tags: bash

I have a list of directories and would like to move files in each of these directories by creating a set of folders and then moving with a wildcard.

What I have so far is:

```
for dir in $(ls -d */); do
    mkdir "$dir/Summary_CSV" 
    mv "*SUMMARY-ABC.csv" $dir/Summary_CSV
done
```

The directory is created fine (verified) but I consistently get an error saying that the the files does not exist.

```
mv: rename SUBDIR1///*SUMMARY-ABC.csv to SUBDIR1///Summary_CSV/*SUMMARY-ABC.csv: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like you are moving the same file `SUMMARY-ABC.csv` in each iteration of the loop. After the first iteration, the file has been moved!

Comment: oops, edited, there should be a wildcard there...

Comment: See: `whatis mv` and `whatis cp`

Comment: Bash wildcards have to be outside of quotes, otherwise they are not expanded. Use `mv *"SUMMARY-ABC.csv" $dir/Summary_CSV`. But my previous comment still apply...

Comment: Sorry jmd, I don't quite follow. I have multiple files in the "sub" directories, file1-summary-ABC.csv, file2-summary-ABC.csv. When I cd to SUBDIR1 and then use   `mv *"SUMMARY-ABC.csv" Summary_CSV` the files move correctly, but not in the loop. I imagine that I'm not actually in $dir while in the iteration, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
mv "*SUMMARY-ABC.csv" $dir/Summary_CSV
```

Try the following or don't use `"` double quotes at all:

```
mv "${dir}"/*SUMMARY-ABC.csv $dir/Summary_CSV
```

You successfully created the folder "Summary_CSV" under each sub-directory (SUBDIR1/2/3 etc) but while copying, you were NOT copying from each "sub" directory.

Also, the command for `for` loop for catching directory, should change from:

```
for dir in $(ls -d */); do
```

To:

```
for dir in $(ls -l|grep ^d|sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*/ /g;s/\/$//"|cut -d' ' -f9|tr '\012' ' '); do
```

otherwise, you'll get symlink to an actual folder (which will result in "No file found, because you would have already moved the file from the actual folder or symlink (for that folder) whichever is listed/picked first).

For the full solution: Try this from any folder:

```
giga@myLinuxMachine /tmp> rm -fr dir; mkdir dir; cd dir; mkdir sub-{dir1,dir2,dir3}; for d in `ls -1`; do touch $d/f{1,2,3} || true; done; find .;

./sub-dir1
./sub-dir1/f3
./sub-dir1/f2
./sub-dir1/f1
./sub-dir3
./sub-dir3/f3
./sub-dir3/f2
./sub-dir3/f1
./sub-dir2
./sub-dir2/f3
./sub-dir2/f2
./sub-dir2/f1
giga@myLinuxMachine /tmp/dir> : lets move files f1-3 to Summary_CSV folder inside each sub-dirN folder
giga@myLinuxMachine /tmp/dir>
giga@myLinuxMachine /tmp/dir> for dir in $(ls -l|grep ^d|sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*/ /g;s/\/$//"|cut -d' ' -f9|tr '\012' ' '); do echo "- Moving all sub-directory: ${dir}/f* files to "${dir}/Summary_CSV" folder"; mkdir ${dir}/Summary_CSV; mv ${dir}/*f* ${dir}/Summary_CSV; done; echo -e "\n\n\n- Lets see what we got after moving\n\n"; find .
- Moving all sub-directory: sub-dir1/f* files to sub-dir1/Summary_CSV folder
- Moving all sub-directory: sub-dir2/f* files to sub-dir2/Summary_CSV folder
- Moving all sub-directory: sub-dir3/f* files to sub-dir3/Summary_CSV folder



- Lets see what we got after moving


.
./sub-dir1
./sub-dir1/Summary_CSV
./sub-dir1/Summary_CSV/f3
./sub-dir1/Summary_CSV/f2
./sub-dir1/Summary_CSV/f1
./sub-dir3
./sub-dir3/Summary_CSV
./sub-dir3/Summary_CSV/f3
./sub-dir3/Summary_CSV/f2
./sub-dir3/Summary_CSV/f1
./sub-dir2
./sub-dir2/Summary_CSV
./sub-dir2/Summary_CSV/f3
./sub-dir2/Summary_CSV/f2
./sub-dir2/Summary_CSV/f1
```

Comment: downvote was an error, my bad! However, despite trying `mv "${dir}"/*SUMMARY-ABC.csv $dir/Summary_CSV` or the no quotes and `for dir in $(ls -l|grep ^d|sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*/ /g;s/\/$//"|cut -d' ' -f9|tr '\012' ' '); do` I get the same error of no such file or directory.

Comment: I pasted the whole testable solution above in my reply. Try that. I'm creating a dummy `dir` folder, under that, I'm creating 3 sub-dirN folders. Under each sub-dirN folder, I'm creating 3 files (f1,2,3) an then using the `for` loop, I moved all `f*` or `*f*` files into Summary_CSV folder inside individual sub-dirN folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a similar error. `- Moving all sub-directory: 10:26/f* files to 10:26/Summary_CSV folder
mkdir: 10:26: No such file or directory
mv: rename 10:26/*f* to 10:26/Summary_CSV: No such file or directory
- Moving all sub-directory: 10:26/f* files to 10:26/Summary_CSV folder
mkdir: 10:26: No such file or directory
mv: rename 10:26/*f* to 10:26/Summary_CSV: No such file or directory
- Moving all sub-directory: 10:26/f* files to 10:26/Summary_CSV folder
mkdir: 10:26: No such file or directory
mv: rename 10:26/*f* to 10:26/Summary_CSV: No such file or directory`

Comment: I am running bash on Mac OS, although I'm don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: I found a solution on another post that has solved it... `find CSV -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*SUMMARY.csv' | while read -r FILE; do
    DIRNAME=${FILE%/*}
    mkdir -p "$DIRNAME/SUMMARY_CSV" && mv "$FILE" "$DIRNAME/SUMMARY_CSV/"
done`

Comment: Yea, that's another way of doing it. you learnt, find cmd's options, parameter substitution `%` or `#` and a cleaner script.